# Why do FirstPersonControls.js stop functioning when another event listener is added?

Tags: javascript, events, three.js

I'm trying to write a 3d environment with FirstPersonControls.js for the movement and the following for the mouseclick listener:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(adblocks);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);


    }
}
```

and in init():

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
```

I've done this on another document and it worked fine, however, this time I'm trying to include FirstPersonControls.js.

In FirstPersonControls.js, I disabled the mousedown and mouseup listeners, by commenting out the listeners, like this:

```
//this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', bind( this, this.onMouseDown ), false );
//this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mouseup', bind( this, this.onMouseUp ), false );
```

That worked fine. FirstPersonControls.js works fine by itself. However, when I add the extra listener for the MouseDown event, the key input (w, a, s, d, q, r, and f) stops responding. If I hold down a key immediately at page load, that key will work until I stop, then everything stops responding. Also, another thing I don't understand, and this may be related, which is why I'm mentioning it, is if I comment out this line in FirstPersonControls.js:

```
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousemove', bind( this, this.onMouseMove ), false );
```

Nothing is changed. Everything keeps functioning exactly the same, which doesn't make sense to me, because I thought that's where the mousemovement event is binded to the document.

Comment: The code for [FirstPersonControl.js](http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/controls/FirstPersonControls.js.html)

Comment: Please show your setup code (html, how and in what order uou load the scripts etc, preferably as a fiddle) and also, what browser is this?

Comment: I made an attempt. I don't know how to include three.js in fiddle, but here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/9CSFW/1/

Comment: Also, it's in Chrome. I just want to be able to move around in three dimensions, freeze the camera (like in FirstPersonControls.js), and be able to click on things as well. For some reason the event listeners are disabling one another, which I don't understand. I even tried rebinding the event listeners on every render, but that didn't work either (not too surprisingly, since that seems unnecessary, as I thought there was a Listener queue somewhere in the workings of JavaScript) .

Answer (score 0):

The FirstPersonControl.js script adds a listener function for the mousedown event. So does your code. When a mousedown event occurs, the last event handler is called first, and normally, the other event handlers should be called afterwards. However, this:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

prevents the event from bubbling up to the other event handlers. I believe the removal of this line should be sufficient to resolve the problem you're describing.

Comment: Wouldn't commenting out the listener bindings for mouseclick in three.js, like this: `//this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', bind( this, this.onMouseDown ), false );
 //this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mouseup', bind( this, this.onMouseUp ), false );` work to solve that?

Comment: Well, I tried that. The weirdest thing happened. Now it only registers the click when I'm moving backwards (the 's' key is down).